# Wordpress: cannot see content in page.php, only sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created my own theme and copied and pasted the code from other standard Wordpress themes into my page.php but it won't show the content, only the sidebar if the code calls for it.

An example of the code for page.php that I copied from Twentyseventeen:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

I have created many different custom page templates already and they all  display the content just fine.

I've created a very standard new page with the default template (page.php) and added text in the admin panel (so not directly to the template) but this text, or any shortcodes or other input, does not get displayed when viewing the finished page.

Can't figure out what is missing. Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't have the file content-page.php in template-parts/page?  If not, either copy and paste the whole template-parts folder from the Twentyseventeen theme or replace the line ' get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );' with 'the_content();'

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming it would be something like that, will give it a try now (y).

Comment: No problem! Could you mark my answer as correct please?